# Am I able to publish an app that I built for a client through my own accounts?

Tags: app-store-connect, google-play-console

I have an apple developer account and a play store account for my own app.

Am I able to publish an app that I built for a client through my own accounts?

Doing some research on apple developer account, learning the client has to create an account and give my access to it.

When I research for the play store account I can't find any direct answers. Can I publish it under my own account?
If no, does my client need to make the account themselves or can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can publish your client's app to your Google Play account and you can then give access to the app to your client.
This way your client will have full access to his application.